# Linearly Independent or Dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove or disprove the following:

If a set $T=(x_{2}-x_{1}, x_{3}-x_{1}, ..., x_{k}-x_{1})$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, then $S=(x_{1},x_{2}, ..., x_{k} )$ is a set of linearly independent vectors.

> Actually this is not true. For example, take $x_{1}=[1, 0]$ and  $x_{2}=[2, 0]$. It's obvious that vectors in $T=([1, 0])$ are linearly independent (because there is only one vector) but vectors in $S=([1, 0], [2, 0])$ are not linearly independent. But I was just wondering what would it be if we think of it in the case $k \geqslant 2$.

Comment: You can always take $x_1 = 0$ to get a counterexample.

Comment: Also if $x_1 , \dots, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, you cannot have a set of $k$ linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Surely not: Pick any basis $(x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and any vector $x_1$.

Comment: I tried to prove in a general way, but it seems there is a fallacy somewhere. Could you please tell me where is wrong in my proof?
If $T$ is linearly independent, the only solution to the following is a trivial solution. ( that is, $c_{2}=c_{3}=...=c_{k}=0$)
$$c_{2}(x_{2}-x_{1})+c_{3}(x_{3}-x_{1})+...+c_{k}(x_{k}-x_{1})=0$$

So isn't the following equation means all coefficient must be 0, and thus implies linearly independent?
$$−(c_{2}+c_{3}+...+c_{k})x_{1}+c_{2}x_{2}+...+c_{k}x_{k}=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x_1 , \dots, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq k$, you can construct a counterexample as follows: Let $x_2 = e_2, \dots, x_k = e_k$ with $\left\{ e_i \right\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, let $x_1 = e_2 + e_3 + \cdots + e_k$. The set of differences $\left\{ x_i -x_1 \right\}$ is linearly independent, but the set $\left\{ x_i \right\}$ is not since $x_1 = x_2 + \cdots +x_k$.